# How to match a custom subdirectory to root namespace in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have just started a C# project. I am using visual studio community 2019. I want to configure Visual Studio such that the root namespace is matched to a subdirectory of the project directory.

Suppose, my application name is `DemoApp` and root namespace is `DemoApp`. I create a folder `src`. Now I create a class `MyTextBox` in `src` folder. It creates the class having namespace `DemoApp.src`. I want that Visual Studio should create `MyTextBox` class with namespace `DemoApp`. Again if I create a folder `Forms` in `src`, and a class in `Form1` in `Forms`, it should have a namespace `DemoApp.Forms`.

I searched a lot but could not get the desired. It is possible? If possible, what are the steps? Thank you.

Comment: _Add - New Folder_

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I know how to create a folder. I want to match root namespace to a subfolder say `src' so that I can move all the code to that folder. The problem is the templates used to generate classes. They match root namespace to project directory.

Comment: Use the backspace or delete keys on your keyboard to change the namespace (remove the .src)?

Comment: @Jard This is what I am doing currently. To be precise, I am using backspace.

Answer (score 0):

Your question specifies that you want "Visual Studio" to create the class in the "DemoApp" namespace. Getting Visual Studio to do what you want is not directly possible, although you could possibly create a class template or something of that nature.

**However**, a relatively easy "workaround" is to create the class at the level you want the namespace to be (such as the root or "DemoApp" level), and then in the solution explorer you can drag the class into the "src" folder after creating it. It will (in VS 2019 at least) retain the original "DemoApp" namespace.

**Another** option would be to simply edit the namespace manually once you have created the class, changing this:

```
namespace DemoApp.src
{
    class MyTextBox
    {
    }
}
```

To this:

```
namespace DemoApp
{
    class MyTextBox
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I am even interested if there is an indirect solution in the limits of VS. BTW thanks for your answer.